# Insert from table only when the Value of a column is Unique

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SummerCourse(AgeMax, AgeMin, CashDiscount, EndCourse, InitCourse, Link,
     Name, Photo, SchoolId, ThematicId, SalesforceId)
SELECT 16, 6, '2019-07-02 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-07-27 00:00:00.0000000',
       '2018-07-02 00:00:00.0000000', 'ww.link.com', S.Nombre_Convocatoria,
       'img-little.jpg', S.IdCentro, 4, '01s4E00001222AQQAY'
FROM dbo.AuxTab S 
WHERE  S.Nombre_Convocatoria NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM dbo.SummerCourse);
```

I Want to insert from an aux db, only the first time that s.Nombre_Convocatoria appears, right now the first time the script add 17 rows(More than one time each name) and the second time 0 but should add only 7 rows the first time and 0 the second time.
Thanks

Example
 SummerCourse has the column name and more, auxtab has column (nombre convocatoria) and more I want to add only the first time that a name is in auxtab
"Pepe" "Luis" "Luis" "Luis" "Tim" "Tim"
So SummerCourse should only has Pepe,Luis, Tim rows

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL and not MS SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry SQL Server yes.

Comment: Can you try to add some sample data which makes this a reproducible problem?

Comment: Could you please clarify this _"the first time the script add 17 rows and the second time but should add only 7 rows"_? why first 17, then 7...

Comment: "Second time 0"

Comment: When S.Nombre_Convocatoria is same in auxtab  table which row S.IdCentro value you will need to insert? That value is also same for all same names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering S.IdCentro is int and need to take min value.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SummerCourse(AgeMax, AgeMin, CashDiscount, EndCourse, InitCourse, Link,Name, Photo, SchoolId, ThematicId, SalesforceId)
SELECT 16, 6, '2019-07-02 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-07-27 00:00:00.0000000','2018-07-02 00:00:00.0000000', 'ww.link.com', S.Nombre_Convocatoria,'img-little.jpg', MIN(S.IdCentro), 4, '01s4E00001222AQQAY' 
        FROM dbo.AuxTab S 
        Group By S.Nombre_Convocatoria
        Having S.Nombre_Convocatoria 
        NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM dbo.SummerCourse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get just 1 per each name.

```
;WITH NameRanking AS
(
    SELECT
        S.*,
        NameRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.Nombre_Convocatoria ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -- Your ordering criteria here
    FROM
        dbo.AuxTab AS S
)
INSERT INTO dbo.SummerCourse(AgeMax, AgeMin, CashDiscount, EndCourse, InitCourse, Link,
     Name, Photo, SchoolId, ThematicId, SalesforceId)
SELECT 16, 6, '2019-07-02 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-07-27 00:00:00.0000000',
       '2018-07-02 00:00:00.0000000', 'ww.link.com', S.Nombre_Convocatoria,
       'img-little.jpg', S.IdCentro, 4, '01s4E00001222AQQAY'
FROM NameRanking S 
WHERE  
    S.Nombre_Convocatoria NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM dbo.SummerCourse) AND
    S.NameRanking = 1
```

If you need to insert a particular row for each name, edit the `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER()` to determine which one goes first.